# How to save (not upload) a file created from a Shiny interface?

Tags: web-services, r, interface, shiny

I have asked this question on the Shiny Google group but once it is published it is immediately deleted, I don't know why.

So I ask this question here.

I know how to upload a file created from a Shiny application but I have unsuccessfully spent a couple of hours to find how to save a file on the hard drive. Please could you show me a way to do so ? For instance I'd like to save a file created with sink() or a RData file.

Below is an (artificial) example of one of my numerous attempts. The sweaveSave() function does not work. Please don't pay attention to the plot, it does not play a role in my question.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
##
## function creating a Sweave report 
##
createReport <- function(file){
        sink(file) 
        cat(
"\\documentclass{article}\n
\\begin{document}\n
\\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
This is the Rnw file.\n
<<fig=TRUE>>=
plot(0,0)
@\n
\\end{document}\n") 
        sink()
}

##
## Shiny server
##
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    ##
    ## Create plot 
    ##
    createPlot <- reactive({
        # generate an rnorm distribution and plot it
        titl <- paste0("Exponential distribution with rate ", round(input$parameter,2)) 
    curve(dexp(x,rate=input$parameter), from=0, to=5, main=titl, ylab=NA, xlab=NA)
        })
    ##
    ## output : plot
    ##
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        createPlot()
    })
    ##
    ##  output : download Sweave file 
    ##
    output$sweavedownload <-   downloadHandler(
        filename="report00.Rnw",
        content = createReport
    )
    ##
    ## save Sweave file 
    ##
    sweaveSave <-   reactive({
        if(input$save){
                createReport("REPORT00.Rnw")
        }else{NULL}
    })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar panel
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("parameter", 
                "Rate parameter:", 
                min = 0.0000000001, 
                max = 10, 
                value = 5),
    checkboxInput("save", "Check to save and download")
  ),

  # Main panel
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.save",
      downloadLink("sweavedownload", "Download")
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: It seems to work for me: Checking the checkbox makes the download link appear, and clicking the download link creates and downloads the .Rnw file. The `sweaveSave` reactive expression doesn't execute because nothing calls it; reactive expressions are evaluated lazily. If you want it to execute even if nothing calls it, you need to make it an observer instead, or call it with an observer. See http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#reactivity-overview for more information on the difference between reactive expressions and observers.

Comment: @JoeCheng Thank you Joe. My messages are still spammed today on the Shiny Google group, I can't reply !

You say that works for you. But where is the created file ? For me it does not appear anywhere in the hard drive.

Anyway I would also like to create a file without downloading it.

Comment: @JoeCheng Thank you ! It works with the `observe()` function !

Comment: hi @Stéphane I did not get the observe(), can you put it in the code?

Comment: @user1265067 I'm too tired to write a clean answer. Replace `sweaveSave <-   reactive({...` with `observe({...`.

Comment: @user1265067 But then the code is stupid because there's no need to run `createReport()` again in the `downloadHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

It make it your life easy by using shinyFiles package.

```
install.package('shinyFiles') 
require(shinyFiles)
shinyFilesExample()
```